# Trying to remove circle from sfcartesianchart tooltip

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

So, i am trying to build some financial chart with flutter using sfcartesian charts (syncfusion), and nearly got my desired result. But i cant find a way to remove the colored circle next to the formatted text i have on my tooltip (see image)

Here are my tooltip settings:

```
        tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(
        borderColor: color1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: color3,
        header: '',
        shouldAlwaysShow: true,
        format:
            'point.x\nO: point.open\nH: point.high\nL: point.low\nC: point.close',
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: color2)
        )
```

[Screenshot of my flutter app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1y5m.png)

how do i remove that little purple circle?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly option to remove that color cirle, but usually I will implement my own tooltip widget then it can easily modify, you can try like this :

```
tooltipBehavior : TooltipBehavior(
  enable: true,
  canShowMarker: false,
  tooltipPosition: TooltipPosition.pointer,
  builder: (data, point, series, pointIndex, seriesIndex) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Text('${point.x}\nO: ${point.open}\nH: ${point.high}\nL: ${point.low}\nC: ${point.close}', style: ts400w12px(Colors.white)),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have validated your code snippet and we would like to let you know that you have set the border color for the tooltip in your code. As a result, the border color is applied to the tooltip label. You can achieve your requirement by removing the borderColor property in TooltipBehavior.

```
tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(
    borderColor: color1, //Remove this line. 
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: color3,
    header: '',
    shouldAlwaysShow: true,
    format:
        'point.x\nO: point.open\nH: point.high\nL: point.low\nC: point.close',
    textStyle: const TextStyle(color: color2)
    )
```

Please check and get back to us if you require further assistance.

Regards,

Lavanya A.